# Calling Curl from asp.net

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, curl, asp.net-web-api2

can i call curl from asp.net?

```
curl -i -F file=@fileToUpload.mov -F userEmail=mail.home@gmail.com http://www.xyz.com/items/uploadToPlayground/
```

i have tried this but it didn't work out. i also used http client class in asp.net web api 2 and i couldn't get it done.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.xyz.com/playground/");
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Method = "PUT";

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            using (Stream video = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("~/Data/Last-Firsty-9-634738828480999898358.mov")))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                while (true)
                {
                    int bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Response.Write(response);
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Do you get an error?

Comment: i didn't receive a response when i call it from asp.net i except json response {"itemId": 1908, "id": 1874, "name": "4ba6295096e940ffb70b159a908044dc"}